# Dealing with primary key clashs in client database when synchronizing with the server

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

**Question**

How can I avoid primary key clashes in client/server databases

**Background**

I am synchronizing a number of databases with each other. I have one central SQL Server database and many client SQL Server databases. Now say I have table X in the database which have a primary key ID.

In the first client we have the following IDs in table X:

X (client 1)

--------
1|SomeValue
2|SomeValue
3|SomeValue
4|SomeValue

and in the second client I have

X (client 2)

--------
1|SomeValue
2|SomeValue
3|SomeValue
4|SomeValue

When I synchronize, I want the clients to only upload their data and not to download them.

Now when I synchronize the first client with the server, it will add the primary keys from (1  .. 4). However, when I synchronize with the second client, there will be PRIMARY KEY CLASH. How can I solve this problem?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, Sync Framework and C#.

I have already considered the idea of using GUID as a primary key which is not viable in my case because I am dealing with a legacy database. Also, the idea of reseeding the IDENTITY value which is somewhat error prone. How can I increment an identity column without inserting a value?
P.S: the primary keys are set to be IDENTITY with increment of 1.

Comment: What is your purpose for relying on the client generated primary keys?

Comment: I am gathering information from different cities at the same time. After that, the data are uploaded to the table that resides in the server in the capital.The database is used in survey app which means I have different survey devices "Tablets" and all of them have local database. After gathering the info it is time to submit them to the server. So, it might be the case that the primary key in one local database has the same value as the primary key in the other database. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: Are you able to make any modifications to the legacy database?

Comment: Modifying the legacy database is a big No No for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To support distributed clients capable of inserting records, the schema has to support client DBs creating rows without conflicts. This means either using GUIDs for PKs, or a concatenated key. (ID + ClientID) *either way, schema change.

Manually synchronising client databases otherwise means either checking for conflicting IDs before insert or handling the exception then replacing IDs or allowing identities to be generated for the conflicted records. This means updating all FK relationships. Time consuming and error prone.

Comment: I had the concatenation idea in mind and as it seems, it is the most viable solution. Hopefully, we learn from our mistakes for future projects. thx.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways for this to work.  The first is if there is a guaranteed uniquekey by which both the upstream and downstream databases can refer to that record.  In the case of SQL server the key type you want is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER (aka GUID).

Now, if for some reason you can't use a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, the second best option is to add an additional column for location or something similar.  This column would identify the individual database where the record is coming from.  For example, the first client might have a location ID of 1, the second 2, etc.  You would then modify your existing primary key to be a compound key of this location id and your current ID.

A third option is to not modify the client databases at all, but only add the location id column to tables within the "master" database.  If you are manually synchronizing in code, then the code needs to take into account where the record is coming from and add in the id as appropriate.  This might be difficult, but is certainly possible.

Baring that you would have to reseed the client databases to start their identity values at a particular point.  For example client 1 might get values 1 to 10000 and client 2 might get 10001 through 20000.  However, you can see the potential for failure here.  Not just if the client exceeds your allowed range but also if you setup additional clients and someone screws up the seed values.  Also, it would be a total PITA to fix all existing clients.

---

As a side note, when building an application that you know is going to have a distributed database that needs merging it is almost universally wise to simply use GUIDs as the primary key.  Yes it fragments indexes etc but in this case those downsides are preferable to the complete PITA and possible errors that could occur when you finally merge all that data together.

Comment: As I see, combining the id and the client id would be the best option. I suggested using GUID to my supervisor but it is out of the table as he told me. After all, I only joined the project from the very end. Thx very much.

Comment: Hi, I'm developing a POS application atm and struggling with a similar problem. We have several separate client databases that register their own sales and these should be synced to a central database.
Additional issue is that they should also be able to edit records that were added by other databases, for instance a customer.

Your second option seems the most viable. What would you recommend? Only saving the "location" of a record on initial create, as they could be edited on another database? Guids/uuids are apparently a huge bottleneck if you need to insert lots of records, I read.

Comment: @Laurent: I can say from experience that the "bottleneck" that you've read about concerning GUIDs is incredibly overblown.  One of our databases has a table with over 100 million records.  **All** IDs in this database are GUIDs - all of them.  We go through periods where a million records might be inserted or updated per day and there is zero slow down.  The main DB server has 32GB RAM running SQL 2008 R2.  But if you just don't want to use GUIDs then yes, only save the location id on the initial record create.

Comment: @NotMe: Thanks for your reply. How would you store these GUID's in the database by the way? As a binary(16) or char(36)?

Comment: @Laurent.  The datatype to use is called **uniqueidentifier**.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

further to @Chris's third option, if you're using Sync Framework, you can actually "trick" it into adding an extra column for the server side PK.

see: [Part 1 – Upload Synchronization where the Client and Server Primary Keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/upload-synchronization-where-the-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)