# Synchronizing certain columns in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, microsoft-sync-framework

As a follow up to my old question:

[Dealing with primary key clashs in client database when synchronizing with the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171987/dealing-with-primary-key-clashs-in-client-database-when-synchronizing-with-the-s)

and this blog post

[Part 1 – Upload Synchronization where the Client and Server Primary Keys are different](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/upload-synchronization-where-the-client-and-server-primary-keys-are-different/)

I want to know if it is possible to provision certain columns between the server
and database. For example, I want the server and the clients to sync everything except for the id.

if we have

client 1:
id
1
2
3
4

client 2:
id
1
2
3
4

then the server will have:

id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

The idea is that I need to keep my id columns as identity and auto-incremented.

Comment: do you want to be able to specify only some columns for synching?

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions, do you have an SSIS package syncing the 2 databases?

Assuming you do, there are a number of ways you can still sync the data:

- Using other fields as your primary key (not sure if that's an option)
- Altering your server table to store the original client id and original source
- Writing to an intermediate table which stores the original id and the new id and the source/client.

SSIS provides lots of tools to map data from one source to another.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: In the first point, if you mean by other fields things such as Guid then yes I can do that, but how will the sync code change?